# Flutter Custom Shape

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to make a shape as seen in the photo below with container in Flutter, can you help me for this?

[image]

Comment: Can you include that you've tried so far?

Comment: check https://gist.github.com/pskink/adf730167a48b750a81f1dd197309312

Comment: @pskink should we use `OutlinedBorder` here for simplicity? But seems both are needed to override same amount of code.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh both `OutlinedBorder` and `ShapeBorder` are fine, the first is better if you need, well, an outline around the shape

Comment: @YeasinSheikh but if you don't want to override anything use [PathBuilderBorder](https://gist.github.com/pskink/adf730167a48b750a81f1dd197309312#file-round_polygon-dart-L127) - the sample code is below the class

Comment: Ok, I will try that approach for myself. Others may feel that a little long.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh what is long? you don't have to extend and override **any** class / method, no "class Foo extends ..." - you just use `PathBuilderBorder` directly in your code

Comment: I mean the `PathBuilderBorder`. is a custom class.  Ok, I will give a try

Comment: @YeasinSheikh [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/adf730167a48b750a81f1dd197309312#file-round_polygon-dart-L480) example is the most exhaustive as it shows a morphing button with a custom painting (`pathBuilder`, `painter` and `phase` parameters are used)

Comment: @pskink, just too cool, i mean way tooooo cool. Ready to spend January on it. Thanks for sharing. I was kinda busy with semester exam 

Comment: @YeasinSheikh your welcome, i hope you passed  your exam :)

Answer (score 0):

use this code to create shape like this

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

//Add this CustomPaint widget to the Widget Tree
CustomPaint(
size: Size(WIDTH, (WIDTH*0.3542581280172481).toDouble()), //You can  Replace [WIDTH] with your desired width for Custom Paint and height will be calculated automatically
painter: RPSCustomPainter(),
)

//Copy this CustomPainter code to the Bottom of the File
class RPSCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
        
Path path_0 = Path();
path_0.moveTo(size.width*1.156952,size.height*3.936736);
path_0.lineTo(size.width*1.968605,size.height*3.949394);
path_0.cubicTo(size.width*1.968605,size.height*3.949394,size.width*2.151398,size.height*4.204300,size.width*2.152460,size.height*4.443043);
path_0.cubicTo(size.width*2.153491,size.height*4.675744,size.width*1.977573,size.height*4.936736,size.width*1.977573,size.height*4.936736);
path_0.lineTo(size.width*1.152468,size.height*4.898765);
path_0.lineTo(size.width*1.156952,size.height*3.936736);
path_0.close();

Paint paint_0_fill = Paint()..style=PaintingStyle.fill;
paint_0_fill.color = Color.fromRGBO(216, 216, 216,1.0).withOpacity(1.0);
canvas.drawPath(path_0,paint_0_fill);

}

@override
bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
return true;
}
}
```

Comment: checkout this example https://dartpad.dev/?id=7bc2cf266bd6c18ae39164c23e3e24cd